# Empty virtual function: good practice?

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism, virtual-functions

I have a superclass Student, from which Junior class and Senior class inherit.

```
virtual void student::attend(void){
        //call either Junior's or Senior's attend
        //if attend is called on a Student object, do nothing.
}
 void Junior::attend(void){
    //do stuff
}
 void Senior::attend(void){
  //do stuff
}
```

Basically my virtual method in the superclass is empty right now, all it does is call the right Senior or Junior `attend()`. I don't want anything to happen if the object is called on a Student object.
The reason I am looking into this is, I want to have something like `std::vector <student*> studv` where `studv` will contain both pointers to Senior and Junior and call attend() on every object of the vector without having to specify anything. So, I have two questions:

a) Is this considered good practice? Is there a better alternative?
b) Considering one of my classes that inherit the superclass might never make use of one of its functions, what should I do? Should I delete it in the derived class, or just do nothing?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can actually define the function as pure virtual if you don't want objects of type `student` to be directly instantiated, requiring people to use fully derived types like `Junior` and `Senior`. That would look like `virtual void student::attend() = 0;` in its declaration.

Comment: This will likely end up closed as opinion-based. With that said, my opinion is to make `Student` abstract by using pure virtual functions. My follow-on is to incorporate NVI, or Non-Virtual Interface, meaning your public section will not contain any virtual functions, but regular functions that may end up just calling their virtual (and now protected counterpart). Depending on the class, this may not be necessary, but it can allow the base class to do some sanity-checks or specialized behavior before invoking the class-specific virtual function.

Comment: Adding a bit to what sweenish said about NVI, for small programs it may seem to be boilerplate fussiness.  But as a program grows, the separation of the public facing API from the inheritance facing API is huge, especially for extensibility and debugging.

Comment: @NathanPierson I completely forgot about this possibility, that's what I think I will end up doing. Also @sweenish to make sure I am understanding correct, would you mean having another method in the abstract class, that would call my now protected and virtual `attend()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real question is whether a `student` object will ever be created on its own (versus as a subobject of a `Junior` or `Senior`).  If it won't be created, consider declaring a function which does nothing for a `student` to be pure virtual:

```
virtual void attend() = 0;
```

Then you will *not* be able to create a `student` object on its own - you'll get a compiler error if you try - and also, it's self-documenting as to that fact, and nor do you have to provide an empty implementation.  Several benefits.

Comment: I have decided this would be my approach (I for some reason forgot about this possibility), since `student` has no point of being directly instantiated.